# Assigning class property in a generic function

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code.

```
A a = new A(....); .... a.Prop1 = ...
B b = new B(....); .... b.Prop1 = ...

DoSth(a.Prop1, b.Prop1); 

void DoSth<T>(T curr, T prev) 
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, prev))
    {
        prev = curr; // prev changed, however b is not changed.
        ....
        callSomeFn(b); 
    .....
}
```

Passing an assigning lambda should work.

```
void DoSth<T>(T curr, T prev, Action assign) 
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, prev))
    {
        assign();
    .....
}

DoSth(a.Prop1, b.Prop1, ()=>a.Prop1 = b.Prop1);
```

However it looks quite cumbersome. Is there a better way to do it? (`ref` cannot be used for object properties.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the generics out. Suppose the type is int. You'd have:

```
void DoSth(int curr, int prev) 
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(curr, prev))
    {
        prev = curr;
    .....
}

DoSth(a.Prop1, b.Prop1);
```

Why would you expect "prev = curr" to affect anything outside the scope of the method? You're assigning one local variable to the value of another local variable.

Assuming that this is actually what you want, I suspect that you want to use the ref keyword on the parameters.

Comment: `ref` cannot be used for object properties.

Comment: @terrybozzio So `var bProp1 = b.Prop1; DoSth(a.Prop1, ref bProp1);` should work as expected? (The function will be `void DoSth<T>(T curr, ref T prev) {....}`)

Answer (score 1):

I might be oversimplifying it, but wouldn't something like this work?

```
T DoSth<T>(T curr, T prev) 
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, prev))
    {
        return curr;
    }
    return prev
}

a.Prop1 = DoSth(a.Prop1, b.Prop1);
```

Comment: `DoSth` will use `b` in the `if` block. So I cannot write the function this way. I've updated the question.

Comment: So change the signature to take a and b and call `a.Prop1 = DoSth(a, b);`